# Javascript regex for Twig templates contents

Tags: javascript, templates

I use a Rich Text Editor to allow online modification of Twig templates. Twig is a template engine using the following syntax to display variables:

```
{{ object.property }}
```

It also uses functions to generate URLS, such as:

```
{{ url('mr_message_read', {id: message.id}) }}
```

Now what i want is to display, next to my editor, the list of TWIG variables **and** functions used in the template. For this, i retrieve the current content as HTML with twig "keywords" as shown above. To extract keywords, i use the regex below:

```
var reg = /{{[^}]+}}/g;
var match = text.match(reg);
console.log( match );
```

This will work work **example 1** but not for **example 2**, as the Twig function requires the **}** string. So, i tried several other syntaxes to allow "*anything except }}*". None of them seem fit:

```
    var reg = /{{[^}]+}}/g; // GOOD but ignores second example
    var reg = /{{[^}}]+}}/g; // Idem
    var reg = /{{[^}}]*}}/g; // Idem
    var reg = /{{(^}}+)}}/; // null
    var reg = /{{(^}})+}}/; // null
    var reg = /\{\{[^\}\}]+\}\}/g; // Ignores second example
    var reg = /\{\{[^}}]+\}\}/g; // Ignores second example
    var reg = /\{\{[^\}\}]+\}\}/g; // Ignores second example
    var reg = /\{\{[^[}}]]+\}\}/g; // Ignores second example
```

I'm struggling now. I guess it's an escaping issue, but i'm stuck :)

**Sample content :**

```
<p>{{ author.fullname }} wrote you a message. Read it here: <a href="{{ url('mr_message_read', {id: message.id}) }}">Messagerie</a>.</p>
<hr />
<blockquote>
<p>{{ message.content|nl2br }}</p>
</blockquote>
```

---

**EDIT: My solution based on Thomas code**

```
function getTwigTags(){

    var str = CKEDITOR.instances['form_content'].getData();
    var regex = /{{\s*([^{]*{([^{]*):\s*(.*?)}.*?|[^{]*)\s*}}/g;
    var keywords = new Array();
    let m;

    while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
        // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
        if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
            regex.lastIndex++;
        }

        // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
        m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
            if(match !== 'undefined' && groupIndex == 1)
                // console.log(`Found match: group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
                keywords[keywords.length] = match;
        });
    }

    return keywords;
}
```

Comment: Why not just [`{{(.*?)}}`](https://regex101.com/r/Ax9uWQ/2)?

Comment: even better without the `?` as `{{(.*)}}` less steps when it's greedy! I think there's no need to be lazy in this case.

Comment: When i use "all" selector, i get a strange result with the sample content i just added to my question. I get two results, fetching both first and second tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```js
const regex = /{{\s*([^{]*{([^{]*):\s*(.*?)}.*?|[^{]*)\s*}}/g;
const str = `{{ url('mr_message_read', {id: message.id}) }}
{{ object.property }}`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
      if(match !== 'undefined' && groupIndex > 0)
        console.log(`Found match: group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hm, almost. If you try your code with my string, the first result is unaccurate and catches two first keywords in one string. I'am adding the sample string to my question now.